# Schema compare between project and snapshot

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools, schema-compare, dacpac

I use Visual Studio 2013 with SSDT to develop my database projects. Some projects within solution have dependencies on others.
I create deploy/update script with Schema compare tool. I find differences between current project state and the latest project snapshot. After that I create new snapshot.

Now I have to use another computer. When I try to compare project and snapshot I receive a number of errors "The reference to external elements from the source named 'SOMEPROJECT.dacpac' could not be resolved, because no such source is loaded." 
I think that the problem may be in folder names - previously solution was in "d:\projects\solution name\", now in "c:\solution name\". I can not use disk D: on the new computer.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Remove the reference and add the correct location if it exists would be the first thing to try. You can also try editing the sqlproj file directly to do this, but using the GUI is likely easier if there are only a couple things to tweak.

Comment: the problem is in snapshots, but not in projects

Comment: Have you looked in the SLN or sqlproj file to see how those files are referenced behind the scenes? If you're getting a problem with the various files that used to work, that's the first place I'd check to see how "SOMEPROJECT.dacpac" is referenced in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a copy of someproject.dacpac. Rename it to Someproject.zip. Unzip the file. Open the extracted model.xml file. Locate the portion of the header that lists the references. Locate the referenced files. Place a copy of the referenced files in the same directory as someproject.dacpac. If that fails, then perhaps you could use the dos command subst to create a path that maps to the true location of the referenced files.